# How to get fatal exception log on android?

Tags: android, forceclose

My app crashes without notification randomly(screen turns to black and go back to home screen), even I have implement ACRA in my app already. I think this is somehow fatal exception which ACRA can't catch it also.

Due to it happens randomly, I can't connect my phone and debug it all the time. Is there some way to get the history log of my app which I can find out what is really happen when it crashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a logcat app, such as [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result) on your device. Next time after a crash open it up and filter on your package name.

[CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) can stream the logcat to file, allowing you to search it afterwards (once a crash has occurred).

Comment: I know Logcat debug, but the point is, the logcat only shows the recent log of system. When i have the crashes i cannot do online debug imediately, normally 2 or 3hours after the crash. I just wondering if there is some way to access the log file 3 or 4 hours ago.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have updated my answer with another app (CatLog) that can RECORD the logcat (ie. stream it to file). Maybe give that a go (then just search the file for error with your package).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe this is one solution. But I have to root the phone, otherwise in jellybean only the app own log can be seen.